# mysql pass parameter to subquery

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation

I have this table:

[image]

```
select a.id, a.title, a.link, a.mclass, b.myids 
from menu a 
left outer join ( select parent, GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',') as myids 
                  from menu 
                  where parent = id 
                  group by parent) b ON a.id = b.parent 
where a.parent='0' and mid='horizontal'
```

[image]

My inner select for special id do this:

```
select parent, GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',') as myids 
from menu 
where parent = '256'
```

[image]

can't get this result

[image]

Comment: Provide sample source data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO script, not as a picture. Show desired output for this sample data as table-formatted text.

Comment: If you use more than one table (even when this is 2 copies of the same table) then **always** add alias to **each** table and add table alias to **each** column.

Comment: *My inner select for special id do this* Use LATERAL if your MySQL version allows.

Comment: No there is a only one table. Difference because I forgot delete some unnessary fields from.

Comment: This two queries work fine separate but together not working.

Comment: *No there is a only one table.* Your `left outer join` tells that more than one table is used. Without variants. The fact that they are copies of the same table changes nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a self join of the tables and aggregation:

```
SELECT m1.id, m1.title, m1.link, m1.mclass, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(m2.id) myids 
FROM menu m1 LEFT JOIN menu m2
ON m2.parent = m1.id
WHERE m1.parent = '0' AND m1.mid = 'horizontal'
GROUP BY m1.id, m1.title, m1.link, m1.mclass
```